# Email template 'test_email_template' is not defined in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, email-templates, system.xml

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Tender Module</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <resource>FM_Tender::quick</resource>
            <group id="option" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Options For RFQ</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable RFQ</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>
                <field id="date" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Estimated Days Required To Reply</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>                                         
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Email Options</label>
                <field id="recipient" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Send Emails To</label>
                    <validate>validate-email</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="sender" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Email Sender</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="template" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Email Template</label>
                    <comment>Email template chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="email_reply" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Reply To Customer</label>
                    <field id="subject" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Subject</label>
                        <comment>Enter The Subject Of The Email</comment>
                    </field>
                    <field id="body" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <comment>Enter The Body Of The Email</comment>
                    </field>
            </group>
            <group id="upload" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Upload Restrictions For RFQ</label>
                    <field id="allow" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Allowed File Extensions Only</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Please Enter the extensions you allow customer to upload files with.<br/>
                         <b>Note:</b>Empty field means disable this feature<br/>
                         Please use comma's to separate  each extension (example:<b> jpg <font color=red>,</font>flv<font color=red>,</font>txt</b>)]]>                         
                        </comment>
                    </field>
            </group>
            <group id="google_options" translate="label"  type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Google Captcha Keys</label>
                <field id="captchastatus" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>

                <field id="googleprivatekey" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Google Captcha Secret Key</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>  
                    <comment>Get Key From https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="captchastatus">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
                <field id="googlepublickey" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Google Captcha Site Key</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>  
                    <comment>Get Key From https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="captchastatus">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="tender_email_template2" label="Quick Form" file="quick_form2.html" type="html" module="FM_Tender" area="frontend"/>

    <template id="tender_email_requirement2" label="Requirement Form" file="quick_requirement2.html" type="html" module="FM_Tender" area="frontend"/>


</config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <tender>
                <option>
                    <enabled>1</enabled>
                    <date>5</date>
                </option>
                <email>
                    <recipient>
                        <![CDATA[hello@example.com]]>
                    </recipient>
                    <sender>custom2</sender>
                    <template2>tender_email_template2</template2>
                    <requirement2>tender_email_requirement2</requirement2>
                </email>

                <!--<email>-->
                    <!--<send_email>quick_requirement_template</send_email>-->
                <!--</email>-->

                <!--<email>-->
                    <!--<recipient>-->
                        <!--<![CDATA[hello@example.com]]>-->
                    <!--</recipient>-->
                    <!--<sender>custom2</sender>-->
                    <!--<template>quick_requirement_template</template>-->
                <!--</email>-->
                <email_reply>
                    <subject>Quick RFQ</subject>
                    <body>Quote Received ...</body>
                </email_reply>
                <upload>
                    <allow>jpg,jpeg,png,gif</allow>
                </upload>
            </tender>
        </default>
    </config>
```

Email template 'test_email_template' is not defined in magento 2 admin

how i can solve this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and its resolved by following change.

If you check your **system.xml** file you can find that you path for system config for email template field is **test_email_template** because test is the section id and email is the group id and template is the field id so basically Magento takes it as **section_group_field** as email template id.

You need to change the template ID in **email_templates.xml** from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="tender_email_template2" label="Quick Form" file="quick_form2.html" type="html" module="FM_Tender" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="tender_email_requirement2" label="Requirement Form" file="quick_requirement2.html" type="html" module="FM_Tender" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="test_email_template" label="Quick Form" file="quick_form2.html" type="html" module="FM_Tender" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="tender_email_requirement2" label="Requirement Form" file="quick_requirement2.html" type="html" module="FM_Tender" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Comment: i will try and inform you.......

Comment: <resource>FM_Tender::quick</resource>   what is use of resouce tag in system.xml

Comment: resource defined the ACL rule which the admin user must have in order to access this configuration

Comment: i given my module name is that ok....

Comment: now i'm getting error 

Email template 'tender_email_template' is not defined.

Comment: Did you use that id some where else? If yes then leave as it is and create new one. Or delete cache, page_cache, view_preprocessed etc and try again.

Comment: after runing all commends showing error ....

Comment: Then create one more template with mentioned ID in my answer.

Comment: $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))

i'm getting error on this line

Comment: Save the system config once and test again. What is the value of XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE?

Comment: i fixed bro......

Comment: XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE  value i put wrong.....

Answer (score 0):

Actually  i put wrong value for

```
XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE
```

so that that error is showing ...